# Trouble hand-writing a sensor_msgs::Joy

Tags: ros, joystick, joy, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I have a mobile wheeled robot that can be controlled through a joystick. I am trying to replace the joystick with another device but I also would like to leave the controller of the robot untouched. Since the controller read a sensor_msgs::Joy I'm trying to "hand-write" it and then publish it but I fail to set the dimension of the axes and button vector (and therefore their values). I tried both axes.resize() and set_axes_size() and they are not working but I suspect that, since i don't have the physical device, I'm failing to provide some needed parameters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12325/trouble-hand-writing-a-sensor_msgs::joy/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main concern is the button/axis mapping in the subscriber. Each robot interprets joy messages differently. You need to know what fields you have to emulate. For example, the Xbox 360 controller works as such:

```
#define XBOX_AXIS_LHORZ     0
#define XBOX_AXIS_LVERT     1
#define XBOX_AXIS_LTRIG     2
#define XBOX_AXIS_RHORZ     3
#define XBOX_AXIS_RVERT     4
#define XBOX_AXIS_RTRIG     5
```

If you wanted to publish to the left stick vertical axis (up/down) to tell the robot to go forward, you could do the following in the publisher:

```
sensor_msgs::Joy joy_msg;
joy_msg.axes.push_back(0.0); // Left Horizontal
joy_msg.axes.push_back(1.0); // Left Vertical (-1.0 through 1.0)
joy_msg.axes.push_back(0.0); // Left Trigger
joy_msg.axes.push_back(0.0); // Right Horizontal
joy_msg.axes.push_back(0.0); // Right Vertical
joy_msg.axes.push_back(0.0); // Right Trigger

publisher.publish(joy_msg);
```

The `.push_back()` method appends a new value to the "axes" vector. If you don't add to the vector, it will be empty. If it's empty when you try to access it with `axes[i]`, you'll get a segmentation fault. The above code will generate a new message for you to publish to your robot.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-12-13**:
@erpa: Variable size arrays such as axes and buttons are realized with std::vector. If you are not familiar with the C++ standard containers, take a look at this reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-13**:
You have to do a buttons.push_back() for each button as well. I believe the value of buttons is either 0 or 1.

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-12-13**:
I quickly tried on my laptop and it seems to work! Tomorrow I'll check with the actual robot, thanks a lot!! By the way even if now I'm able to generate the correct vectors for joy_msg.axes and joy_msg.button axes.size() still return 0!

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-12-13**:
what does exactly axes.push_back() does? My concern was with the publisher because the joystick I'm trying to emulate has 8 axis but when I try to access to joy_msg.axes[i] and set the desired value I get a segmentation fault (and checking the dimension of the vecotr with joy_msg.ages.size() it's 0)

**Comment by [Jo_Han_Solo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32380/jo_han_solo/) on 2017-10-25**:
Hey there, I know it's almost 6 years after you guys had this conversation.

While this appears to work, I'm having issues with my "joy_msg" filling up. Each new command from the controller adds to the vector array until it eventually begins to lag. Any idea why? @DimitriProsser